# How to create different shortcut in menu bar using " alt + key "?

Tags: c++

How to write program in c++ for a form where I can create short cut keys using alt,the way we have in windows by default..e.g. alt+f for files,alt+e for edit?How to code it by ourselves?

Comment: please put some effort into writing clear and answerable question. what GUI framework do you use?

Comment: Get Petzold's book, Programming Windows, and read it. Then you'll understand the basics of Win32.

Comment: I want to do it in visual studio.

Comment: Any link if you could provide me with where i can find implementation for the same.

Comment: for windows platform how we can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best source of information for Windows programming is MSDN.  The tricky part is knowing what the thing you are looking for is called.  In this case, MS calls these ["accelerators"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).